# How to change the path of a file downloaded from a script in Jenkins

Tags: c#, csv, jenkins

We have a job configured in Jenkins to build the UI tests written in C#. One of the tests will download a `.csv` file from the application. Normally when the script is executed from VSTS or the command line it stores the file in `C:\Users\******\Downloads`. But when it is executed through Jenkins the file is downloaded at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\50.0.2661.94`.

How can we change the path in Jenkins so that it can download the file in normal path?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Add a shell step to move the file to your desired location

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Mowgli. The thing is that we first remove if there is a existing .csv file in the folder and then download the new csv file and then check if it is downloaded or not. So, as Jenkins is downloading the csv file in another location than the desired location the tests are failing.
Is it possible modify the default location of the downloads through Jenkins to our desired locations?

Answer (score 0):

Goto *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → <kbd>***Advanced...***</kbd> button on top → *Workspace Root Directory* – this is the place where your job will download your files, specifiy the path you want.

Comment: I'd not recommend doing it this way. This is a system-wide setting and concerns the workspaces of _all_ jobs.